# Is there a way to permalink a section of a Wikipedia page?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I know how to link directly to a section-title of a Wikipedia page; I do it often to support an answer.

I also know how to permalink an article as it stands right now (so I can be sure it still says what it said when I was looking at it). I do this occasionally (particularly with pages that have changed to be substantially worse in the past).

What I don't seem to be getting to work is linking to a section-title when I'm permalinking.

Does anyone know if it's possible? If so, how?

Comment: Like that: [en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Theodicy&oldid=682868551#History](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Theodicy&oldid=682868551#History) ?

Comment: @amoeba Ah, I should have though to try it that way, even though it looks weird to my eye. I was essentially doing "...Theodicy#History&oldid=682868551"

Comment: Everything before `#` specifies the url and goes to the server to request the HTML output. All the parameters separated by `&` have to be part of that (`oldid` in this case). Everything after `#` is used by the client browser to scroll down the resulting HTML page and so has to follow the url itself. Ergo: first `&` then `#`.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy if you know what you're doing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some possible links:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy#History
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Theodicy&oldid=682868551
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Theodicy&oldid=682868551#History

You can get #1 by browsing to the desired Wikipedia page, #2 by clicking on a section name in the Contents of that page, #3 by going to `View history` of that page and choosing a particular revision, and #4 by clicking on a section name in the Contents of that revision page.

(Remark based on comments: `#History` *has* to be in the very end of the URL, because it is an *anchor* that is used by the client browser to scroll down the HTTP page; everything before the `#` is used by the server to form the HTTP page itself.)